# Is the solution to this Linear DE bounded?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

given $\frac{\mathrm{d^2} y}{\mathrm{d} x^2} -xy=0$ , is the solution bounded when
 $x\to\infty $ 
Well, I've been trying to solve this but I haven't been able so far, I got an implicit solution $yln - y=x^3/6+ct+d$ , where "c" and "d" are constant. Anyway, I am not sure how to do this and the I am asked to graph the solution too.

Comment: This is Airy DE. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AiryDifferentialEquation.html

Comment: You're right, I also tried with power series and I got the same result, if I just do the limit of "x" to infinite, it's infinite, so it's not bounded, right?

Comment: Yes It's unboud.